# Moving wrapfigure into margin

Tags: wrapfigure

I would like to emphasize the take home messages of a text by placing them into separate figures, `.5\textwidth` wide and extending `.1\textwidth` into the side margin. Using the `wrapfig` package almost gets me there.

> - How do I move the `wrapfigure` environment *slightly* (not entirely) into the left margin?
> - Or even better, slighly into the outside margin of a `twoside` document?
> - Is `wrapfig` the best package to use?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{.5\textwidth}
\hrule\smallskip
\textit{\Large  Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi.}
%\textit{\Large\lipsum[2][3]} does not work
\smallskip\hrule
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wrapfig includes an optional overhang parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wrapfigure` environment admits also the keys `i`/`o` for inside/outside in the case of two-sided documents. Furthermore there is a overhang option, which can be given as global dimension or as optional parameter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\wrapoverhang}{.5cm}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{O}{.5\textwidth}
\itshape\Large 
\hrule\medskip
Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi.
\medskip\hrule
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[2-6]

\begin{wrapfigure}{O}[2cm]{.5\textwidth} % this overhangs 2cm
\hrule\smallskip
\textit{\Large  Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi.}
\smallskip\hrule
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[7-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that with your current setup `\textit{\Large ...}` you are using a large font but with the normal baseline (since the group is closed before the paragraph is set). I've added an alternative with the corresponding baseline (that is of course in part a matter of taste).